# Can't make gallery photos lock screen wallpaper (Samsung S3)

Tags: lock-screens, wallpaper

I can only make the preinstalled wallpapers the wallpaper for my lock screen. I can choose an image from my photo gallery, select and crop it and then save it, but the lock screen just stays the same. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4, but see if you can set a common wallpaper through a similar path: `Settings > My device > Display > Wallpaper > Home and lock screens`.

**UPDATE 2013-12-06**: Another solution you could try is to clear the default app for pictures. If it's a 3rd-party app like QuickPic, go to your phone's Application manager (via Settings), select the 3rd-party app, and do a `Clear defaults`.

Afterwards, open the `Gallery` app (not a 3rd-party app like QuickPic), pick a photo, left-soft-click to open a menu, and click `Set as`. You can pick either: Home screen, Lock screen, or Home and lock screens. [Source](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-s-iii/210553-cant-change-lock-screen-wallpaper.html).

Comment: Thankyou for your advice. Unfortunately neither the home or the lock screens change when I try to do it this way. The home screen will change if I change it on its own, but the lock screen won't budge :s

Comment: @Chelsea (1) Maybe you could try setting a photo from a gallery, or a live wallpaper. Then, restart and try it again? (2) Did you install any 3rd-party lockscreen?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. I did not install any 3rd party lockscreen

Comment: @Chelsea Do you have another gallery app installed? Like Quickpic perhaps?

Comment: @Chelsea I updated my answer. See if that helps.

Comment: Hey! Sorry didn't get back to you sooner. Clearing defaults for the only picture viewer I have (Gallery) didn't work, but resetting defaults on all my apps did, so you put me on the right track :) thank you very much!