# Can't make gallery photos lock screen wallpaper (Samsung S2)

Tags: lock-screens, wallpaper

I have a Samsung S2 and until recently changing the lock screen was fine, however suddenly (potentially after apps were synced), I am unable to change my lock screen using a gallery photo, using both the change lockscreen prompt through Gallery itself, from holding down the homescreen as well as through the Settings. I am only able to change it to one of the factory Wallpapers.

Changing the home screen is fine, and as far as I know my only third-party editing app is TwCrop, which I got to try and fix the problem (it didn't).

Comment: Related, if not identical: [Can't make gallery photos lock screen wallpaper (Samsung S3)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58114/16575). Hm, is the number following the "S" a counter? Cannot find the question for "S1"...

Comment: It is the same problem, however I was unable to comment on that post so had to make a new one. How do you mean 'counter' sorry?

Comment: Try to use the answer in the link Izzy shared. If it helps, upvote it.

Comment: Are you using the stock, pre-installed launcher ([TouchWiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz))?

Comment: @Justine "counter" was rather kidding. Comparing the title of the two questions, the only difference is yours ends with "Samsung S2", and the other with "Samsung S3". Like a count-down, so I was waiting for "Samsung S1". But instead we got the [Galaxy S3 mini](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58639/16575) – well, in a way also a "smaller number" ;)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I attempted to use the answer in Izzy's link but I am unable to set a common wallpaper, through settings, and I do not have any third-party app's installed, as far as I am aware. @Ivan- I assume I am as I am not tech savvy enough to have ever changed it :) Unsure how to know for sure though.

Comment: @Izzy- thanks for the explanation, I get it now :)